# cudaErrorInvalidValue error when calling cudaMemcpyToSymbol

Tags: c, cuda, gpu, gpgpu

When calling the function `cudaMemcpyToSymbol`, I get Invalid value error (`cudaErrorInvalidValue`). The code where the error occurs is something like this.

```
__constant__ int c_queryLength; //Length of query sequence in chunks of 4
...............
if((cuda_err = cudaMemcpyToSymbol(c_queryLength,&queryLengthInChunks,
  sizeof(queryLengthInChunks),0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice))!=cudaSuccess)
{
 // Check which error occured;
 ...............
}
```

Here the value of `queryLengthInChunks`, which is of type `size_t`, is 36. Why am I getting this error. Any possible reasons for that?

Comment: Are you sure that `size_t` is the same size as a CUDA `int` on your system, i.e. 4 bytes ?

Comment: size_t is 8 bytes on my system, as I'm using a 64 bit windows system. Does it pose any problem in this case?

Comment: Yes, of course - a CUDA int is only 4 bytes. You can't just copy an 8 byte variable to a 4 byte constant.

Comment: Ya Indeed its working. Thanks! Maybe you can put your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: OK - good to know - I've made the above comments an answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check whether `size_t` is the same size as `int` on your system. If `size_t` is 8 bytes and `int` is only 4 bytes then the call will fail - you can't just copy an 8 byte variable to a 4 byte CUDA device constant.